# MYSQL HAVING (not) with ROW_NUMBER() why it returns different row counts

Tags: mysql, having

I have simple query:

```sql
SELECT 
  definitions.rowid, 
  chars, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY chars, definitions.rowid) AS nr 
FROM definitions 
INNER JOIN words ON definitions.word = words.rowid 
WHERE definitions.valid = True 
HAVING chars > 20
```

on my computer(intel) it returns 36k records

but on client computer(ryzen 2990wx) it returns 99k records (having not working - chars starts form 1)

if i remove join it works ok on both computers

if i remove row_number it works ok on both computers too

if i replace "having" with "and" it works ok on both computers too

on both computers are the same version of mysql (8.018) and the same tables ...

I have a presentation tomorrow - I need any ideas

```
CREATE TABLE `definitions` (
    `rowid` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `word` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `definition` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_polish_ci',
    `chars` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `difficult` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '99',
    `islocked` BIT(1) NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    `valid` BIT(1) NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`rowid`),
    INDEX `word` (`word`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_polish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=100038
;


CREATE TABLE `words` (
    `rowid` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `word` VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_polish_ci',
    `display` VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_polish_ci',
    `difficult` TINYINT(4) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `islocked` BIT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `valid` BIT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`rowid`),
    INDEX `word` (`word`),
    INDEX `display` (`display`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_polish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=57009
;
```

creation code the same on both computers - created by the same instalator ...
query is a part of table browser/editor with just in time loading (datagridview with virtual mode) so will be very difficult modify its logic by night

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your question to show us your table definitions. Please give a little background on your problem. The make and model of computer machine has nothing to do with this case. The contents of the database tables almost certainly do, and they are almost certainly different between your machine and your customer's machine. The `HAVING` clause only makes sense if your query uses `GROUP BY` or other aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

HAVING is used with GROUP BY to filter the aggregated data. In your case, you should just add HAVING  chars >  20 to the WHERE clause as AND chars >  20

Comment: this query is generated automatically (depends on how the user filters / sorts the tables) - group by appears very often there